# Size of boxes representing tree nodes in Decision tree plot in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, visualization, decision-tree

Sklearn function tree.plot_tree displays boxes representing tree nodes with different sizes. Does anybody know what size of box represent? I’m not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning of it,

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#tree-structure

it is just a default setting.

If you want to adjust the size, you find a useful question and answer here:

[Sklearn plot_tree plot is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447378/sklearn-plot-tree-plot-is-too-small)